# Need SQL command that will insert a row after specific row

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I need SQL command that will insert a row after specific row.
 Example:-

Before table

```
Id.         Name.      
1.           Xyz.          
2.           Xyz
3.           Xyz
```

Want result need to add 'Abc' data after each 'xyz' having same id like:-

```
Id.         Name.      
1.           Xyz.    
1.           Abc      
2.           Xyz
2.           Abc
3.           Xyz
3.           Abc
```

Comment: SQL tables are by SQL standards definition **orderless**, which means there isn't a `INSERT ... AFTER` kind of command... If you would need a order you need to define it which selecting `SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: doing what you requested is not very good on performance, the more your table grows the more time it will take to move all rows to make room for the inserted row. In real-world you typically insert the rows at the bottom of the table and then sort the table using `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

You need `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT id, Name
      FROM table t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID, 'Abc'
      FROM table t
    ) t
ORDER BY ID, NAME;
```

This will not insert row, it just provide you run time view. If you want only insert then you need to truncate your table (note : take a backup of current table ) & perform insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE table_sample SET column = column+1 WHERE column >= some_value_here ";

INSERT INTO table_sample (id, column_name) VALUES
(NULL, 'value_here');

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO your_table 
SELECT Id
       ,'Abc' AS Name
FROM your_table
Where Name = 'Xyz'
```

I am not sure if `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` is needed, it depends on your table. But this query should do what you need. It will get all the rows that contain the Xyz value and use the same id and a different name. Then if you order by Id because remember ordering is never guaranteed if you don't use order by