# Need SQL command that will insert a row while taking id from row

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpg

I need SQL command that will insert a row after specific row. Example:-

Before table

```
Id.         Name.      
1.           Xyz.          
2.           Xyz
3.           Xyz
```

Want result need to add 'Abc' data after each 'xyz' having same id like:-

```
Id.         Name.      
1.           Xyz.    
2.           Xyz
3.           Xyz
1.           Abc
2.           Abc
3.           Abc
```

Note this command work on 1000 data

Comment: There is no such thing as "after" in a table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need SQL command that will insert a row after specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122499/need-sql-command-that-will-insert-a-row-after-specific-row)

Comment: Really, you should have provided feedback on your other question instead of asking it a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (id, name)
SELECT id, 'Abc'
FROM yourTable
WHERE name = 'Xyz';
```

This assumes that you only want to duplicate rows having `Xyz` as the name.  If you instead want to duplicate *every* record with an `Abc` version, then just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to add a data 'abc' by referring the data 'xyz' with same id from 'xyz' in table, let me know your command will work or not and I have to retain the 'xyz' also in table

Comment: Thnx tim for your time